# How would I paint 3D Blender files using Java?

Tags: java, 3d, blender

I'm working on a 3D game and I google everything for this answer. How can I add 3D .obj files into my Canvas and paint them using methods in Java?

For example, if I have a grass block, I'd like to maybe paint it green or something. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to do a lot more research, there is no easy way of doing this in java, .draw3D(...), take a look at http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ for example

Comment: Google "OpenGL". If you don't give up there, you would probably end up at "http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut". Once you learn that, you need to get a way to interact with OpenGL via Java. I suggest LWJGL.